# IPv6 address to CIDR block

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, cidr

I'm trying to add a IPv6 address to the security group of an EC2 instance, but I need to specify it as a CIDR block. It's a full IPv6 address, like this fake address: 2600:1003:c10c:b42c:1956:fed1:db13:ff42. How can I convert this to a CIDR block/range?

Comment: I don't believe security groups support IPv6 at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As vcsjones said, AWS security groups do not support IPv6 - primarily because EC2-VPC does not support IPv6.

See [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=147601) on the AWS forums for some relevant info.

[This thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=672099) has more info on Amazon's lack of support for IPv6 on EC2.